# How to use result cache while using joins in SAP HANA?

Tags: join, caching, hana

```
SELECT
    cntdpts."PROJECT_SID",
    cntdpts."USER_SID",
    "CNTDPTS",
    "CNTQUERIES"
    FROM (
    SELECT
        "PROJECT_SID",
        "USER_SID",
        COUNT("DATA_POINT_SID") AS "CNTDPTS"
    FROM
        CNTDPTS
    GROUP BY
        "PROJECT_SID",
        "USER_SID" WITH HINT(RESULT_CACHE) ) cntdpts
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        "PROJECT_SID",
        "USER_SID",
        COUNT("QUERY_SID") AS "CNTQUERIES"
    FROM
        CNTQUERIES
    GROUP BY
        "PROJECT_SID",
        "USER_SID" WITH HINT(RESULT_CACHE) ) cntqueries ON
    cntdpts."PROJECT_SID" = cntqueries."PROJECT_SID"
    AND cntdpts."USER_SID" = cntqueries."USER_SID" WITH HINT(RESULT_CACHE)
```

I am having troubles with using cached table functions. If I run the two subqueries "cntdpts" and "cntqueries" individually they return the result within <100ms (because they use the cache of the table function CNTDPTS and CNTQUERIES. However if I run the full query with joining the two subqueries it takes >5s and HANA does not seem to take advantage of the cached results from the subqueries. Is there any HINT I still need to add maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `WITH HINT(RESULT_CACHE_NON_TRANSACTIONAL)` to your outermost query.

See also https://help.sap.com/viewer/9de0171a6027400bb3b9bee385222eff/2.0.05/en-US/3ad0e93de0aa408e9238fa862e4780df.html